# Typescript - How to get the type of an optional nested prop in an interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

The code below throws me the ts error: `Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ id: string } | undefined'.` because group is optional. In spite of that I want to get the type of id. How can i do that?

```
interface list{
  group?: {
    id: string; 
  }
}

const something: list["group"]["id"] = {} as any;
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDbAM5gN4FgBQyyA5lAPYCuADgPwBcyehRywAJg1lKMQNzIEiAXwIj8BBGRBZkGMgFsIYABY8G6LAG0ARKUpVtAXR3sjyALyMhyOBhsgAnryA)

(Ignore the `{} as any`, this is just an example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript provides the `Partial` and `Required` helpers to make all properties of an object either optional or non optional.

You can read more about typescript utility types [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype).

So in your case you can use `Required<list>` to turn `group` into a non optional property:

```
interface list{
  group?: {
    id: string; 
  }
}

const something: Required<list>["group"]["id"] = "foo"
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDbAM5gN4ChnIDmUA9gK4AOA-AFzJ4EHAAmdWUohA3MvsgL65BuBCRBZkGEgFsIYABac6AJQgBHMsCgRmAHnRYAfAG0ARMXIVTAXTMsbyALzJTMEiVNA)